# Can you help me with a font licensing question (AKA what is the licensing for my font)?

Tags: fonts, licensing, copyright, font-management

I'm asking this question on behalf of the occasional new members who ask questions in the following categories (fill in the blanks as appropriate):

- Does anyone know the licensing terms for ***_*__*_*__**  font?
- I have conflicting licenses for ***_*__*_*__**  font, can somebody clarify them for me?
- I have a font with ***_*__*_*__**  license terms, can I use it for ***_*__*_*__**  purpose?
- I have a font and don't know the license terms, can I use it for ***_*__*_*__**  purpose?
- Font ***_*__*_*__**  was included with ***_*__*_*__**  software/operating-system.  Is it legal to use it for ***_*__*_*__**  purpose?
- Can I embed ***_*__*_*__**  font in my product?

Answer (score 7):

**In every question about licensing terms, the correct procedure is to contact the rights-holder of the font or typeface.**

The actual owner of the typeface, and licensing, is the only one who with the authority to answer your questions about license terms.  If you for some reason cannot contact or get a response from the owner of the rights in question, your next step should be to contact a copyright attorney.

While many people in the StackExchange community are design experts, you do not want to put your product and your pocketbook in danger by relying on legal advice from people who are simply not in a position to answer with authority.