# What exactly is a font license?

Tags: font-licensing

What a font license? Is it a document?

For example, if I bought a a particular font, what license will I get? Do I get something like a certificate/document? And how will they know that it's licensed to me when I use it in a website or software?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you help me with a font licensing question (AKA what is the licensing for my font)?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3317/can-you-help-me-with-a-font-licensing-question-aka-what-is-the-licensing-for-my)

Comment: @ZachSaucier The info will likely be relevant to OP but the duplicate doesn't really address which form licenses are provided in.

Comment: IMO we should make the other a canonical and Eddie a bit

Answer (score 0):

You can usually view a font's license on the site of the seller before buying the font. It outlines what you are allowed to do/unallowed to do with the font you've bought the license to. It usually also comes with the download of your font, sometimes in the form of a text or PDF file. Licenses vary, some are less restrictive than others.